# mean or median in table in R (like pivot in excel)

Tags: r

I try to get out of my data a table and I don't know how to do this.
This is my data. The header is in German.
Because of this is my r-code in german too. sorry for that but I hope someone can help me with the subject .

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7daa.png)

I would like to get this output as a pivot table in r. I tryed to translate in english:

[pivot in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH3Um.png)

In r i tried different ways to get to a solution (library(pivottabler):

This on worked a bit, but I couldn't calculate the median.
[counting the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxSFl.png)

[version with testing median calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ctV.png)

Here I don' get the value into the table
[table without values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24RX1.png)

I also tried this. But this is not the output I am looking for.
[group_by and summarise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FUGc.png)

Thanks for your help.
mg

Comment: Hi to Germany, Welcome to stackoverflow. Please go through this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example>.

Comment: What is `3'057.63` ? The same as 3057.63 = Three thousand fifty seven comma sixty three? Big-mark? or grade? TIME?

Comment: it is earnings not time like euro

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're doing and what the problem is trying to read & compare data between pictures, and without knowing what your headers are. That's why we ask for a [mcve]

Comment: Total mean of what,? and which variables want you to calculate? ` K_CHF_GV   DB3 DB3_rel L_294_OPmin` as in your png or all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the pivot right in R.
I used the library("pivottabler") with the data.frame "bhmtrains". This worked now. Thanks for your ideas.

[result of the pivottabler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpIJS.png)

```
library(pivottabler)
qhpvt(bhmtrains, c("=","TOC"), "TrainCategory", 
  c("Mean Speed"="mean(SchedSpeedMPH, na.rm=TRUE)", "Std Dev Speed"="sd(SchedSpeedMPH, na.rm=TRUE)"), 
  formats=list("%.0f", "%.1f"), totals=list("", "TrainCategory"="All Categories"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to give you a more applicable answer if you gave us a more [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

However, what I think you want is easily accomplished with functions from the `dplyr` package. This answer uses the built-in `iris` dataset. It groups by the categorical variable `Species` and calculates the median by Species for all numeric columns in the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), median))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa              5           3.4         1.5          0.2
2 versicolor          5.9         2.8         4.35         1.3
3 virginica           6.5         3           5.55         2
```

To calculate the mean over all numeric columns, use `mean` where the above code has `median`.